# How to pass by reference in C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-value

I am writing a Quick sorting class mimicking the code given in "Algorithms 4" by Sedgewick. The original code is written in Java. I translated in C# the core part but it doesn't seem to work. It seems like the problem is in the line `a = a.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray()` but I don't know how to correct it.

I tried to add `ref` in the `Sort`s and `Partition` method signatures but once I call the function `Sort(ref a)` in `Main`, the compliler complaints that `cannot converte ref System.String[] to ref System.IComparable[]`. 
I also tried to make the first `Sort` return an `IComparable[]`, the sorted array. However, when I call it in the `Main` like this `string[] nums = (string[]) Sort(nums)`, it throws a runtime error says `Unable to cast object of type 'System.IComparable[]' to type 'System.String[]'.`

```cs
public class Quick
{
    public static void Sort(IComparable[] a)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        a = a.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
        Sort(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
    }

    private static void Sort(IComparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (lo >= hi) return;
        int p = Partition(a, lo, hi);
        Sort(a, lo, p - 1);
        Sort(a, p + 1, hi);
    }

    private static int Partition(IComparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int i = lo, j = hi;
        IComparable p = a[lo];
        while (true)
        {
            while (Less(a[++i], p))
            {
                if (i == hi)
                    break;
            }

            while (Less(p, a[--j]))
            {
                if (j == lo)
                    break;
            }

            if (i >= j) break;

            Exch(a, i, j);
        }
        Exch(a, lo, j);
        return j;
    }

    private static void Exch(IComparable[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        IComparable tmp = a[lo];
        a[lo] = a[hi];
        a[hi] = tmp;
    }

    private static bool Less(IComparable a, IComparable b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) < 0;
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] nums = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nums[i]);
        }
        Sort(nums);
        Console.WriteLine("After sorting:");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nums[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The seconde WriteLine should print out the sorted array but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried adding `as IComparable<string>` in the method call?

Comment: Please could you clarify by "it doesn't seem to work" and why you believe the solution is to use pass-by-reference? (I don't think you need to use `ref` at all here...)

Comment: @JonSkeet By saying "It doesn't seem to work" I mean after calling `Sort()` in the `Main` method, the printed out array is still the original array (unsorted). I am not sure what the solution is and thought pass-by-reference might work because the `Sort()` method doesn't return anything and the array passed to the method needs to be modified. I am really new to C# and only has some limited experience in C++, where people can pass by reference of an object.

Comment: You can pass by reference in C# as well, but I don't think that's the right approach here - or at least, you'd probably need to make significant changes. The simplest fix here is probably to move the shuffle part into the `Main` method - the act of sorting does *not* require shuffling to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you so much for the quick fix suggestion and it worked! But could you possibly also show me how to achieve the goal without moving the shuffle part to the `Main` method. Like I said in my post, I tried adding ref to the signature and not adding and both failed. The code I give above is my direct translation of the Java counterpart in the book where the author put the shuffle part in the `Sort()` method so that the shuffling is blind to the supposed caller of `Sort()`. I'd like to retain the same logic.

Comment: Then you need to shuffle *in place*, which is what I suspect the Java code already does. The problem is that you're creating a new array with the shuffled content, then sorting that... leaving the original array alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not pass by reference, it is this line, as you have identified:

```
a = a.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

You are giving `a` a new value, which is different from just modifying the contents of `a`. Since the `Sort` method sorts the array in place, you should not create a new array, and the array doesn’t have to be shuffled before you sort it.

So deleting these two lines should make your code work:

```
Random r = new Random();
a = a.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
```

You seem to encounter some problems when you try to return the array from `Sort`. You can fix this by making all your methods generic, with a generic parameter `T` constrained to `IComparable<T>`:

```
public static T[] Sort<T>(T[] a) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    Random r = new Random();
    a = a.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
    Sort(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
    return a;
}

private static void Sort<T>(T[] a, int lo, int hi) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    if (lo >= hi) return;
    int p = Partition(a, lo, hi);
    Sort(a, lo, p - 1);
    Sort(a, p + 1, hi);
}

private static int Partition<T>(T[] a, int lo, int hi) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    int i = lo, j = hi;
    T p = a[lo];
    while (true)
    {
        while (Less(a[++i], p))
        {
            if (i == hi)
                break;
        }

        while (Less(p, a[--j]))
        {
            if (j == lo)
                break;
        }

        if (i >= j) break;

        Exch(a, i, j);
    }
    Exch(a, lo, j);
    return j;
}

private static void Exch<T>(T[] a, int lo, int hi)
{
    T tmp = a[lo];
    a[lo] = a[hi];
    a[hi] = tmp;
}

private static bool Less<T>(T a, T b) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    return a.CompareTo(b) < 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, a question not directly related to C#, why do you say the array should definitely not be shuffled before sorting? The book "Algorithms 4" says shuffling is crucial to the predictability of the algorithm's running time and protects against the worst case.

Comment: @tmsh I see. It does protect against the worst case, but I tend not to worry about performance issues before I encounter them. In that case, you should use a  shuffle algorithm that shuffled the array in place, instead of returning a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the sorted array since, like you said, it's passed by value and not by reference.
Add return type instead of void to the Sort method and return a;

And change

Sort(nums);

to

nums=Sort(nums);